# How to determine if a given date is a working day in C++

Tags: c++

My idea is to construct a string array with all the holidays. Then compare the input date with the array. Seems it quite inconvenient that have to type in all the weekend's dates etc. by hands. Any better ideas?

Comment: Do you have access to Excel, or a spreadsheet tool with similar functionality? With the WEEKDAY function in Excel, and some string construction, you could create this in a few minutes

Comment: @mock_blatt Thanks. I was wondering if there are some open lib that I can use to make things look neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to first determine the day of the week of the given date, to decide it to be Sunday or Saturday.

Use this logic to determine it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

For the code use this link: [GeeksforGeeksCode](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-day-of-the-week-for-a-given-date/)

and the compare the days, to mark it as holiday or a working day.

Comment: If any of the suggestion helps, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Howard Hinnant's free, open source C++11/14 date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), here are all the weekends in 2017.

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    for (sys_days sd = jan/1/2017; sd < jan/1/2018; sd += days{1})
    {
        weekday wd = sd;
        if (wd == sat || wd == sun)
            std::cout << sd << '\n';
    }
}

2017-01-01
2017-01-07
2017-01-08
2017-01-14
...
2017-12-23
2017-12-24
2017-12-30
2017-12-31
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set an initial day, like *Jan 1st 2017*, it's Sunday. And you can calculate if other days are workday or not.

For example, you have an array called `days` has 7 elements, stores Monday to Sunday. Like:

```
std::string days[] = { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun" };
```

And when you want to know if a day is workday, let's say *Jan 3rd 2017*. First you can calculate difference between the day you want to calculate and initial day (which is *Jan 1st 2017*). In our case it is 2. Then the result is `days[2 % 7 - 1]` (`-1` because our initial day is set to Sunday. If we set initial day as Monday, `-1` is not necessary). *Jan 3rd 2017* is Tuesday, that means it is a workday.

Comment: Then the question switch to how to calculate a input date and the initial date, which is conquerable.